# How to update position of Angular cdkDropList?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cdk-drag-drop

I have this issue for quite some time and can't figure it out and wanted to ask if it's possible to help. Somehow the position of the 'drop area' of the `cdkDropList` **does not update** when I animate it.

- **What I want to do**

Create a `cdkDropList` `<div>` which acts as a container (let's call the `cdkDropList` `<div>` **Bin**) in which I drop `cdkDrag` elements from another list (let's call the `cdkDrag` elements **Item**).
The **Bin** should *fly in* when **Item** is picked up and *fly out* when **Item** is dropped (no matter if it's back into the original `cdkDropList` or **Bin**).

- **What happens:**

The animation works fine, but when I drag **Item** into the **Bin**, the **Bin** isn't recognized. What I mean by 'not recognized' is that the `cdkDropListDropped` function of **Bin** is not triggered.
This problem only occurs when I do the animation by picking up and dropping **Item**. I also tried to animate the **Bin** with a button which I click to let the bin appear/disappear and that works fine (but it's not the way I want to implement it).

- **Example:**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cvbare?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

In this Stackblitz example I recreated the thing that's not working since posting my code would be too much and hard to understand without context.

**Note:** In the console of the example you will see `Dropped something` when **Item** is dropped into the **Bin**. When **Item** is dropped back or anywhere outside the bin it will print `Dropped back` in the console.

- **What I tried so far:**

Using...

...`CSS` animations instead of `Angular`

...`ChangeDetectorRef`

...`Timeout`

I'm really stuck and don't know how to resolve this issue and would appreciate any kind of advise or help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like this is a bug and is currently not resolved yet. Just found these tickets on Github related to this bug:

[Ticket #1](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/14703)

[Ticket #2](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/18638)

[Ticket #3](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/17736)

I guess I just have to wait for a fix.